# Customizing Colors of React Native Chart Kit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, charts, react-native-chart-kit

A basic line/area chart has been created for a React Native app using the `react-native-chart-kit` package, as shown using the code below.

**Question:** How can we change independently the style/color of the components of the plots? Such as the dots, line stroke, area, axis, tick labels etc...

When the `color` parameters in `chartConfig` is changed, it appears to affect almost the entire chart, including the axis tick labels, gridline, area under line plot.

Is it possible to define the color for each individual property of the chart?

[image]

**Code:**

```
import { LineChart } from 'react-native-chart-kit';
import { Dimensions} from 'react-native';
const screenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width

const data = {
labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June'],
datasets: [{
    data: [ 20, 45, 28, 80, 99, 43 ],
    color: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(134, 65, 244, ${opacity})`,
    strokeWidth: 2 // optional
}]
}

const chartConfig = {
backgroundGradientFrom: '#fff',
backgroundGradientTo: '#fff',
color: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(63, 143, 244, ${opacity})`,
strokeWidth: 2 // optional, default 3
}

class Test extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <LineChart 
                data={data}
                width={screenWidth}
                height={400}
                chartConfig={chartConfig}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find out if it was possible to style individual dots?

Comment: @per_jansson Not yet!

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code that I am using to create a chart. See the 'propsForDots' section to style the data points.

I know that's only part of what you were asking for help customizing, but this is a start.

```
<LineChart
  data={{
      labels: labelArray,
      datasets: [
          {
              data: valueArray
          }
      ]
  }}
  width={Dimensions.get("window").width} // from react-native
  height={220}
  yAxisInterval={1} // optional, defaults to 1
  chartConfig={{
  backgroundColor: "#444",
  backgroundGradientFrom: '#444',
  backgroundGradientTo: '#444',
  decimalPlaces: 2, // optional, defaults to 2dp
  color: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(0, 110, 199, ${opacity})`,
  labelColor: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(255, 255, 255, ${opacity})`,
  style: {
      borderRadius: 16
  },
  propsForDots: {
      r: "6",
      strokeWidth: "2",
      stroke: "#fff"
  }
  }}
  bezier
  style={{
      marginVertical: 8,
      borderRadius: 16
  }}
/>
```

In the props for dots, r is the radius of the dot, stroke width is the border size, and stroke is the color of the border.

I'm still experimenting with this library as well, which is why I came across this question. Hopefully this helps you out and others who may be searching for some of the same things.

Answer (score 2):

For dot color we can use getDotColor props, with this we can edit the each dot and define a color for each dot

**getDotColor** Defines the dot color function that is used to calculate colors of dots in a line chart and takes (dataPoint, dataPointIndex)

```
getDotColor={(dataPoint, dataPointIndex) => {
console.log('dataPoint ---->', dataPoint);
console.log('dataPointIndex --->', dataPointIndex);
//based on condition we return the color as string
if (dataPointIndex === 0) return 'red';
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the colour of the area under the line, set useShadowColorFromDataset as true.

```css
chartConfig={{

    useShadowColorFromDataset: true, //Default is false

}}
```

Comment: Your answer needs better formatting, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help on writing clear and well-formatted answers 